# Trailing null in Json

Tags: php, json, datatable

I'm using `ajax` method in `DataTable` to populate the table.
Below is the code

```
$(function(){
        $('#datatable-default').DataTable({
            "ajax": 'data.php'
        });
    })
```

My `data.php` looks like this:

```
$jsons = '{"data": [
                [
                  "Tiger Nixon",
                  "System Architect",
                  "Edinburgh",
                  "5421",
                  "2011/04/25",
                  "$320,800"
                ]
            ]
        }';
        echo $jsons;
```

When the `datatable` is loaded, it gives the below mentioned error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=datatable-default - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Upon inspecting element from Developer Tools in browser, I see that the response is suffix by a `null`, which is stopping the data to populate.
Below is the response from browser:

```
 {"data": [[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", 
"Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"]]}
null
```

What could be the reason for this `null` value in the `response`?

Comment: unsure if this'll change anything but try returning instead of echoing in your data.php

Comment: on returning instead of echoing, it just gives `null` value.

Comment: @brianforan That won't work. If you `return` something, it has to go somewhere. Like a variable which calls a function that returns the result as a value to the variable. By using `return` in this case, it has no where to go.

Comment: Is echo` the last line of the file?

Comment: Seems a bit weird - echoing @user3284463's question, try adding `exit();` directly after the line where you `echo` the json.

Comment: @abbas Something to take into considderation would be that `null` value. If you tried `return` instead and still got a `null` value, it means something else than your variable is returning something. If there's nothing in your code, could it be that you saved the file with a [Byte-order mark](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark)?

Comment: @icecub well to be fair I've never used the `ajax:` property in a datatable but when typing `$.ajax({ })` directly and returning the data from the back end then just handle the data in the javascript, but I'm getting the vibe that the ajax prop does that all for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create JSON objects by hand instead use the `json_encode()` function:

```
$data = [
  "data"=>[
     "Tiger Nixon",
     "System Architect",
     "Edinburgh",
     "5421",
     "2011/04/25",
     "$320,800"
    ]
  ];

echo json_encode($data);
// Since you are not looking forward to receiving anything else, you might just kill the script
die();
```

Comment: Correct. Just use the tools that the language provides :)

Comment: even this has same issue. `null` is preceding after the response.

Comment: @abbas Hmm, if there isn't anything else you want from the file after the echo, you could just kill it using `die()` after the echo statement